# using big binary numbers in java - getting wrong result

Tags: java

I have an array where bytes 1,2,4,5,6,7, represent one big value in this way:

```
   (most significant) byte2-byte1-byte7-byte6-byte5-byte4 (less significant)
```

bytes =   [43, 1, 0, -13, -112, 56, 94, 105, 20, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

how can I get this 48 bits new value?

this is what I tried so far:

```
long byte1 = (bytes[0] & 0xFF);
byte1 = byte1<<32 ;         
long byte2 = (bytes[1] & 0xFF);
byte2 =byte2<<40;   

long time = (byte2|byte1|
                ((bytes[7] & 0xFF) << 24) |
                ((bytes[6] & 0xFF) << 16) |
                ((bytes[5] & 0xFF) << 8) |
                ((bytes[4] & 0xFF) << 0));
```

my expected output of time: 6062749840

I am getting even after using long: 1285963004048

00000000 000000001 01101001 01011110 00111000 10010000 = 6062749840

Comment: What do you expect `<< 32` and `<< 40` to do?

Comment: shift left.....

Comment: Shift left a 32 bit variable by 40 bits?

Comment: so how else can I do it?

Comment: what variable do I need to use that has 64 bits?long?

Comment: yes, please use `long` for 64 bits

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is the output expected ?

Comment: Since an `int` is 32 bits, only the last 5 bits of the amount to shift is used, for a shift in the range 0 through 31 bits. So `<< 32` is the same as `<< 0`, and shifting a 1 zero bits to the left clearly yieids 1. Similarly `<< 40` is the same as `<< 8`. Since `bytes[2]` holds a 0, the result of shifting it will always be 0.

Comment: please look at my try with long

Comment: Using a long, `1L << 40` is 1 099 511 627 776, so how could you expect only 606 274 984?

Comment: maybe i ll write a new question which is more clear

Comment: In your `long` example you are taking `bytes[1]` and `bytes[0]`, but you said you wanted `bytes[2]` and `bytes[1]`. I believe this may account for your wrong result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s pretty straightforward either to run your program in a debugger or insert `System.out.println()` statements to see what is going on. You should learn to use a debugger, it’ll be a good investment. Either method will tell you that the intermediate results are:

```
long byte1 = (bytes[0] & 0xFF); // 43 or 00101011
byte1 = byte1<<32 ;          // 184683593728 or 0010101100000000000000000000000000000000
long byte2 = (bytes[1] & 0xFF); // 1 or 00000001
byte2 =byte2<<40;    // 1099511627776 or 000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000

long time = (byte2|byte1|
                ((bytes[7] & 0xFF) << 24) |
                ((bytes[6] & 0xFF) << 16) |
                ((bytes[5] & 0xFF) << 8) |
                ((bytes[4] & 0xFF) << 0)); // 1285963004048 or 000000010010101101101001010111100011100010010000
```

However, you said you wanted to use byte 1 and 2, not 0 and 1. So let‘s correct your code to do that:

```
long byte1 = (bytes[1] & 0xFF);
byte1 = byte1<<32 ;         
long byte2 = (bytes[2] & 0xFF);
```

Now the result is 6062749840 or 000000000000000101101001010111100011100010010000 as you said you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigInteger` for this if you want to shift left by more than 64 bits for example.

```
BigInteger shiftedNumber = BigInteger.valueOf(initialValue).shiftLeft(n);
```